# Doesn't the broker commit messages in order of their timestamp in Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a scenario where I deploy multiple producers which produce the messages.
The message contains an attribute called **eventTime** which corresponds to when that particular event is raised. I would like to set this **eventTime** as the timestamp in the `ProducerRecord`. I have set it. It may happen sometimes, that:

1. Suppose there are 2 events with timestamps 100,102 which I want to produce.
2. I have 2 producers **A** and **B**.

Now, **A** might get the message with **102 timestamp** *first* and then **B** might get the message with **100 timestamp** second

i.e. to say ***A*** will produce the message with **102** timestamp first and then **B** will produce message with **100** timestamp second.

Therefore, the ordering of messages will be 102, 100 rather than 100, 102.

I have tried the following, but none of them did work.

Setting the `batch.size` and `linger.ms` to high value (2216384,1500) - I am sending a message with key of *long* type, message as *String* type.

```
  //Specify buffer size in config
  props.put("batch.size", 2216384);

  //Reduce the no of requests less than 0   
  props.put("linger.ms", 1500);

new Thread(()->{produce(101,1540964511l,"second","topic-name");}).start();
new Thread(()->{produce(101,1540964498l,"first","topic-name");}).start();
```

As you can see the above timestamp for first is smaller than that of the second. Ideally, the **first** message should be consumed *first* and then the **second** message should be consumed which is not the case. Note that, I have used 101 as the key for both and the partition is also set to 0 for both the messages.

```
public static void produce(long id, long timestamp, String msg, String topic)
   {
      System.out.println("producing .. "+msg);
         producer.send(new ProducerRecord<Long, String>(topic, 0,timestamp, id, msg), new Callback(){
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e)
            {
               System.out.println(metadata);
            }
         });
   }
```

I have also tried using transactions, but still no use.

**Command**

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test --partition 0 --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

**Output**

```
second
first
first
second
second
first
```

If the leader broker's job is to just write to the partition whatever it gets, then there must be some other way provided by the Producer API to produce the messages to the broker in order.

Or atleast, at the broker side, isn't there a mechanism by which it waits for some time, for messages before committing them to the partition?

My question therefore is, how to achieve the ordering of messages using their timestamps?

If a message with a higher timestamp gets produced first, then what is the use of timestamps in the context of message sequencing?

Comment: Kafka guarantees that consumers receive messages they are produced into the stream, not that they are sorted by event time. You'll need to solve this on application level; a single producer, different topics, resorting at consumer etc.

Comment: @daniu then what is the use of timestamps in ProducerRecord?

Comment: TBH I wasn't aware of that field, but I can think of several uses besides record sorting - eg delay measurement, linger evaluation etc

Comment: It's use is to know when events arrived at the server, mostly. It didn't exist until Kafka 0.10.2... Otherwise, your application is forced to include that information within the event itself, if it was required.

Comment: @cricket_007 How can I get the messages of a batch in the producer side?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... You already have the records, as you are calling `.send()` on them. And you have a batch until the time interval passes, or you call `producer.flush()`

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to know if the batch contains a specific number of messages and then do some operation before the batch is produced

Comment: That seems to be an entirely separate question than needing to know how events get ordered. And I don't know if you can get the batch after you call `.send`... Perhaps you should build up an internal ArrayList of a set size, if you need this... Also, the consumer can have a separate batch size than the producer, by the way, but again, you'll have to feed that batch out to another data structure that allows for time-sorting.